# Vertical and horizontal center alignment using flex box

Tags: html, css

I have two `divs` with images inside that I am trying to center horizontally and vertically within the page. They remain pinned to the left of each `div`. How do I resolve this?
My goal is to create two columns, left approx 30% of total width containing voab.png, right remaining 70% of total width containing 3 icons vertically stacked.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("_images/back.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.icons img {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

div.voab {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

div.left {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.icons {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="voab">
  <div class="left"> <img src="_images/voab.png" width="186" height="178"></div>
  <div class="icons"> <img src="_images/insta.png" alt="insta" width="65" height="65" style="padding-bottom: 40px;"> <br>
    <img src="_images/opensea.png" width="65" height="65" style="padding-bottom: 40px;"> <br>
    <img src="_images/twit.png" alt="insta" width="65"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: have not been able to find one. please reference. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The percentage values you've added to `left` and `icons` make the two divs expand to fill the full width of the container. Just remove the `width` attributes and let their width be determined automatically:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("_images/back.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.icons img {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

div.voab {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

div.left {
  height: 100%;
}

div.icons {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="voab">
  <div class="left"> 
    <img src="_images/voab.png" width="186" height="178">
  </div>
  <div class="icons">
    <img src="_images/insta.png" alt="insta" width="65" height="65" style="padding-bottom: 40px;"> <br>
    <img src="_images/opensea.png" width="65" height="65" style="padding-bottom: 40px;"> <br>
    <img src="_images/twit.png" alt="insta" width="65">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that I am trying to create an approx 30/70 spacing (left image centred in the left 30% of the screen; right image centred in the right 70% of the screen).

Comment: When you say right image, do you mean the contents of your icons div?

Comment: Yes. Two containers, left with the voab.png, right with the vertically stacked 3 icons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("_images/back.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.icons img {
  opacity: 0.6;
  align-self: center;
}

.left img {
  align-self: center;
}

div.voab {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

div.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.icons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: end;
  flex: 0 0 70%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="voab">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="_images/voab.png" width="186" height="178">
  </div>
  <div class="icons">
    <img src="_images/insta.png" alt="insta" width="65" height="65" style="padding-bottom: 40px;"> 
    <img src="_images/opensea.png" width="65" height="65" style="padding-bottom: 40px;"> 
    <img src="_images/twit.png" alt="insta" width="65">
  </div>
</div>
```